# Css Selector That Uses html File Name

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

I am styling checkout pages on an eCommerce platform.  I cannot modify the html, insert any javascript, etc.  I can only edit the css files.

There is a spinner icon that appears on two different pages, that I need to style differently on each page.  The HTML on the two pages for the spinner is identical-- no differentiating classes, etc.

Is there a way for me in css to select the spinner by page?  Something like:  processing.html > img?

Comment: Well, firstly, note that not every page has a filename - look at this page for instance. So what you're really looking for is some way of matching the *URL*. As far as I know, however, there is no such thing in CSS, so you'll have to find some existing difference between the HTML in the pages to detect, or ask whoever's in charge of the template to add something.

Comment: Are there any differing attributes in the html you could use to hook on to? If there are you could use something like this: http://css-tricks.com/attribute-selectors/

Comment: With CSS, this is not possible if there is absolutely no difference in the structure of the tags, classes, or ID's. What eComerce provider are you using? Usually they will allow you to change the HTML, JavaScript, ect. if you submit the changes to them. WePay, for example, allows for these  changes.